# How to hide some content from a group of users in Apostrophe CMS?

Tags: user-permissions, intranet, apostrophe-cms

I'm looking into using Apostrophe CMS for an extremely large intranet website. I need to have the ability to have different types of permission levels for users (this can be done), I need to restrict pages for certain users (this can be done), and I need to restrict the ability to view some content in a page (not the entire page) from users with a certain level of permission, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

That is possible using the Personas extension module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/apostrophe-personas. Really that's exactly what the Personas module is for.

You could also use the `data.user._groups` property in templates to see what group they are in and display content that way. You could automate creating `areas` for group by making the area `name` property include the group name (again using that `data.user._groups` property in the template).

Comment: This has been helpful. Thank you!

Comment: The personas module is not suitable for cases where the user *must not* see that content, because they can switch personas just by changing their URL prefix. So it is really more a tool for market segmentation, not permissions.

The second method suggested should work great though.

Comment: Users should not be able to switch personas. Thank you for this clarification, Tom!